# Comparing JavaScript variable with PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style_downloads.css" />
<script>
function theFunction(e){ 
    var x = e.target.innerHTML;
    document.write(x);
}
</script> 
<a onclick="theFunction(event)" href="">Electromagnetic Theory</a> 
<a onclick="theFunction(event)" href="">Manufacturing Technology-I</a>
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root');
    if (!$con) echo "Connection Failed";
    mysqli_select_db($con, 'test') or die(mysqli_error($con));

    $q      = "SELECT * FROM tb1";
    mysqli_query($con, $q) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $q);
    $num    = mysqli_num_rows($result);


    for ($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++) {   
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
        if(?>
        <script>x</script>
        <?php==$row['coursename'])
        { ?>
         <div id="downloads"> <span id="pdfname"><?php echo $row['pdfname'] ?></span> <a href="upload/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>"> <img src="download.png" id="downloadbtn"></a> </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here I want to compare var x of js to $row['coursename'] ie mysql db table entry.
Basically this code is targetting to display db table entry according to onclick event. 
Example:
When I click on Electromagnetic Theory, File displayed on page should be correspending to this course name only.

Comment: If you want to filter values in a database table, then use sql to do the filtering, that's what it was designed to do.

Answer (score -1):

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style_downloads.css" />

    <script>
    function theFunction(e)
    { 
        var itemName =  e.target.innerHTML;

            $.ajax({
                url     : "/ajaxAction.php",
                type    : "POST",
                data    : {'itemName':itemName},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) { 
                console.log("response",response)        
                    if(response.type == "success") {
                        $("#downloads").html('');
                        $("#downloads").html(response.result);                     
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
    }
    </script>

<a onclick="theFunction(event)" href="">Electromagnetic Theory</a>
<a onclick="theFunction(event)" href="">Manufacturing Technology-I</a>

<div id="downloads">
    <span id="pdfname"><?php echo $row['pdfname'] ?></span>
    <a href="upload/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>"> <img src="download.png" id="downloadbtn"></a>
</div>

    <?php
    create file ajaxAction.php
    incluede connection.php

    $itemName   = $_POST['itemName'];
    $con        = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root');
    if (!$con)
        echo "Connection Failed";

    mysqli_select_db($con, 'test') or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $q      = "SELECT * FROM tb1";
    mysqli_query($con, $q) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $q);
    $num    = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++) {   
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
        if($itemName == $row['coursename'])
        { 
            $res = ' <span id="pdfname"><?php echo $row['pdfname'] ?></span>
                <a href="upload/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>"> <img src="download.png" id="downloadbtn"></a>';
        }
     }
    echo json_encode("type":"success","result":$res);
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: Step 1 when we click on Electromagnetic Theory :
we call the javscript function and hit the ajax file:
to this ajax file we send that variable Electromagnetic Theory

Now in this ajax file we fetch data from mysql table and return the result
and result will display in that div.

We need to do this with ajax

Comment: Above code is giving error and not doing required action.

Comment: In which file can u share error and let me know are you able to post data to ajax file

Comment: I don't have much idea about ajax!

Comment: You can study this online  like :https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp